# How to mount azure blob to windows server

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to mount azure blob storage to my windows server 2012R2 as drive, i have already used cloudberry but we cant afford that one, if another way to mount it.

Comment: It is not possible if you don't use 3rd tools, why not mount Azure disks?

Comment: we want more space, azure files give 500 GB only after mounting

Comment: You could mount Azure File Shares, but you could not mount blobs.

Comment: Hi, do you want to mount Azure File Shares or Azure blob?

Comment: yes i know that one, i already mounted File share, we tried lots of tools but most of them was explorer.

Comment: i want Azure blob

Comment: Hi, `Max size of a file share` is `5TB` not `500Gb`. Is this enough for your app?

Comment: Thank, your tips are much useful for me, 5TB not enough for our app.

Comment: 5TB is not enough for your app. So you tell that you spend >$120/month and can't afford $60 one off (5TB on your Azure block blob costs you at least $120/month) for the software you mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, it is not possible to mount Azure Blob directly, please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/3170907-mounting-blob-storage-as-shared-folder-or-drive).

> we want more space, azure files give 500 GB only after mounting

On Azure, `Max size of a file share` is 5TB not 500Gb. More information about Azure Storage limit please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits).